# Is there a way to filter the results of az storage blob list using a condition?

Tags: bash, azure, azure-storage, azure-cli, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to call "az storage blob list" but I only want the return to show me blobs whose lastModified date matches a specific condition (last modified 180 days ago or more).

Current code (Azure Yaml) which returns me all of the blob names

```
echo "==== Blobs in Container  ===="
                  blobsBeforeDirectoryFilter=$(az storage blob list --container-name azureml \
                    --account-name  *** \
                    --account-key *** \
                    --prefix ExperimentRun/ \
                    --query "[].{name:name}" --output tsv)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I only want the return to show me blobs whose lastModified date matches a specific condition (last modified 180 days ago or more).

You can use the `?properties.lastModified < '2023-04-15T00:00:00Z'].name` in the query to get the list of blobs with the last modified date.

**Command:**

```
echo "==== Blobs in Container ===="
$blobsBeforeDirectoryFilter=(az storage blob list --container-name test --account-name venkat123 --account-key 'your account key'  --query "[?properties.lastModified < '2023-04-15T00:00:00Z'].name" --output tsv)
$blobsBeforeDirectoryFilter
```

**Output:**

```
==== Blobs in Container ====
day.csv
impnextapp.txt
```

[image]

**Reference:**
[az storage blob | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-blob-list)